# sql sum on latest price

Tags: mysql, sql

need to prepare annual report on items sold, so prepared one [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7d9c/8) for this... i have price table for each items... so when fetching an item's price i need the latest price by price_dt... thought simple at first.. but spent more time than what i should... :(

report is for total items sold annually

```
price table
'I001', '2014-03-31', '200.00'
'I002', '2014-03-31', '200.00'  //old price
'I002', '2014-05-31', '150.00'  //latest price
'I003', '2015-03-31', '200.00'
'I004', '2015-07-31', '120.00'
'I005', '2015-07-31', '180.00'


items
'I001', '2014-06-30', 'SOLD'
'I002', '2014-06-30', 'SOLD'
'I003', '2015-06-30', 'SOLD'
'I004', '2015-08-30', 'SOLD'
'I005', '2015-08-30', 'UNSOLD'


I001 & I002 are sold in 2014 ('SOLD' status in items table)
I003 & I004 are sold in 2015 (but I005 is not sold yet in year 2015)
```

I002's price is 150 (as that's the latest price)

when i sum the price for each item i need to consider the latest prices

so my final output should be

```
2014     350
2015     320
```

Comment: and sorry for bad english.... :)

Comment: The SQL Fiddle is good, but you should include in your question sample data and desired results.  Your question is rather ambiguous.  It is not really clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the price table again with the max date as

```
select
year(i.sell_date),
sum(p.price) from items i
left join price p ON i.item_id = p.item_id
join (
  select item_id,max(price_dt) as price_dt from price
  group by item_id
)x on x.price_dt = p.price_dt and x.item_id = p.item_id
where i.status = 'SOLD' 
group by year(i.sell_date);
```

Comment: just for curious is there any sub-query solution....or is this itself a sub-query

Comment: Yes its a uncorrelated subquery.